# R: glmnet, lasso applying k-fold crossvalidation on time series

Tags: r, machine-learning

I hope that this is not a dublicate, because I posted the question also on cross-validated. I think that the question also refers to a programming aspect.

I want to "recode" the lasso by myself. However, I'm at the point, where I have to program the k-fold Cross-Validation. Since I will use AR-models im not sure if a "normal" random k-fold Cross-Validation is a good idea, because of the time order structure of time series. It could be then case that my trainings sample would then backcast older values. 
Closer details in the blog of hyndman:
https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/

Regarding to that I've two questoins:
1) Do you know if the glmnet package take time series structure into account (in Cross-Validation)
2) Do you know a way some sources, that show me how I can deal with it ?

If this question is beyond the scope of the forum or dubplicated I will delete the question.

Comment: I dealt with the same issue and I ended up using the package _caret_ which allows to estimate various models and includes the function _glmnet_. The method _timeslice_ inside the train function is what you are looking for. Alternatively, without using _caret_ you can create blocks and avoid the _backcast  older values_ problem using _glmnet_ instead of _cv.glmnet_ for each fold and by evaluating the performance of the trained model in the successive observations with _predict_.

Comment: Im a bit confused about the Hyndman paper. It proofs, that we can apply the "normal" CV on AR(p) that doesnt take the time struture into account